# Google Play Game Services. Real Time Skeleton Application. Player presses back button in waiting room

Tags: google-play-games

I'm troubleshooting an issue I'm having with the real time skeleton (Button clicker example) for Google Play Services. I'm noticing that if player 1 while in the waiting room leaves 
the room by way of pressing the back button before player 2 accepts the invitation that player 2 is still connected and the value of mParticipants is still 2 on the player 2 side even though
player 1 is supposed to have left the room.

Example (Player 1 invites player 2 to a match. The waiting room is opened.):

```
            08-05 17:24:41.886: D/GameHelper(22237): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=10000, resp=RESULT_OK
            08-05 17:24:41.886: D/GameHelper(22237): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
            08-05 17:24:41.886: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): Select players UI succeeded.
            08-05 17:24:41.886: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): Invitee count: 1
            08-05 17:24:41.886: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): Creating room...
            08-05 17:24:41.906: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): Room created, waiting for it to be ready...
            08-05 17:24:43.257: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): onRoomCreated(0, RoomEntity{RoomId=ChEKCQjEutW5sAUQAhABGAAgARDq9JSasuOhhvcB, CreatorId=p_COr0lJqy46GG9wEQAQ, CreationTimestamp=1407284683121, RoomStatus=0, Description=null, Variant=0, AutoMatchCriteria=null, Participants=[ParticipantEntity{ParticipantId=p_COr0lJqy46GG9wEQAg, Player=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=116552246986005424427, DisplayName=Chris Sepich, IconImageUri=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImageUri=null, HiResImageUrl=null, RetrievedTimestamp=1407284683152}, Status=1, ClientAddress=null, ConnectedToRoom=false, DisplayName=Chris Sepich, IconImage=null, IconImageUrl=null, HiResImage=null, HiResImageUrl=null, Capabilities=0, Result=null}, ParticipantEntity{ParticipantId=p_COr0lJqy46GG9wEQAQ, Player=PlayerEntity{PlayerId=113875263239226324701, DisplayName=Eric Sepich, IconImageUri=content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/80784b26/2, IconImageUrl=http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-udm-yatehyg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABw/w0iPFPD2Ijs/s96-ns/, HiResImageUri=content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/80784b26/7, HiResImageUrl=http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-udm-yatehyg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABw/w0iPFPD2Ijs/s96-ns-s376/, RetrievedTimestamp=1407284683151}, Status=2, ClientAddress=null, ConnectedToRoom=false, DisplayName=Eric Sepich, IconImage=content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/80784b26/2, IconImageUrl=http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-udm-yatehyg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABw/w0iPFPD2Ijs/s96-ns/, HiResImage=content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/80784b26/7, HiResImageUrl=http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-udm-yatehyg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABw/w0iPFPD2Ijs/s96-ns-s376/, Capabilities=0, Result=null}], AutoMatchWaitEstimateSeconds=-1})
```

Example (While in the waiting room. Player 1 presses the back button. leaveRoom() is run)

```
            08-05 17:24:46.330: D/GameHelper(22237): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=10002, resp=RESULT_CANCELED
            08-05 17:24:46.330: D/GameHelper(22237): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
            08-05 17:24:46.330: D/ButtonClicker2000(22237): Leaving room.
```

When player 2 accepts the invitation I have checked the length of mParticipants in player 2's application inside of:

```
        @Override
        public void onConnectedToRoom(Room room) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectedToRoom.");

            // get room ID, participants and my ID:
            mRoomId = room.getRoomId();
            mParticipants = room.getParticipants();
            mMyId = room.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(getApiClient()));

            Log.d(TAG, "mParticipants.size():"+mParticipants.size());
            // print out the list of participants (for debug purposes)
            Log.d(TAG, "Room ID: " + mRoomId);
            Log.d(TAG, "My ID " + mMyId);
            Log.d(TAG, "<< CONNECTED TO ROOM>>");
        }
```

The length of the mParticipants array is still reading as 2 even though player 1 is supposed to have left the room at this point. I'm posting this as a question to see if anyone else
has dealt with the same issue. I was hoping to check the number of participants in onConnectedToRoom() and if one of the players has pressed the back button in the waiting room the match
should be terminated and the user sent back to the main screen. Why is the length of mParticipants still 2 here and is there a way to handle this occurrence where one of the players has
pressed the back button inside the waiting room?

I've found the documentation under connecting players but I'm still unable to resolve the problem. Essentially what I'm saying is that after an iteration of:

```
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, mRoomId);
```

The other client still connects as if the player were still in the room because the back button was pressed in the waiting room. Is there a remedy?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of mParticipants isn't the value you're looking for. Players are never removed from mParticipants, they just change state. The Participant that left will have com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Participant.STATUS_LEFT.